# ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanging?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, event-handling

How can I handle an combobox selected index event before the index changes ? Winforms doesnot provide any sort of ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanging event !

Thanks

Comment: What do you intend to do? it has **SelectedIndexChanged** and **SelectedValueChanged** events

Comment: isn't there a Cancel property on the ChangedEvent? I'm guessing this from the top of my head so it might be not true, but have a look into the `EventArgs e` in the `SelectedIndexChanged`, perhaps there is a `e.Cancel` which aborts the event.

Comment: Hey I got the answer. Actually I was looking to 'do something' before the drop down opens. So for that we have `ComboBox.DropDown`. Thanks guys

Comment: @Niraj: was just about to suggest that :)

Comment: @Bazzz: I dint want to cancel the event, but wanted to write some code before the combobox opens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I achieved it using ComboBox.DropDown

No you didn't.  Use the up/down arrow keys to fire the event without using the dropdown.

To use the SelectedIndexChanged event for this, you need a time machine that goes back by less than a microsecond.  It's really unclear why you need this but you can probably get one by deriving your own class from ComboBox.  Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyComboBox : ComboBox {
    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) {
        // Here
        //...
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Insert the code at the dots.  You could for example raise your own event there.

Comment: I want this for re-binding the combobox.

Comment: After reviewing your answer, I can say that your method is much more appropriate. I would take it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it using

> ComboBox.DropDown;

Because my aim was to 'do something' before the combobox opens.