# Combobox DropDownOpened event

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, event-handling

I have a combo box inside a list view. And different items (rows) in the list view need to display (based on some condition) one among 3 sets of combo box items in the respective combo box which is . Right now I am achieving this by using 3 data templates bound to 3 different properties of `List<string>`. I am hooking up the appropriate data templates during the `DropDownOpened` event of the combo boxes.

The problem that I am facing is that I am having to click the combo box twice each time to have it dropped down. I did a `Debug.WriteLine()` to see if my first click does the job of selecting a data template, I found that it indeed does. But just that it does not drop down at the first click itself.

I guess this is because I am changing the data template after the combo box has dropped down its popup and hence it refreshes again whose results are furnished only after I perform the second click.

My question is whether there is any other way of accomplishing what I am trying or do I have to make any changes in my existing `DropDownOpened` event handler.

Please suggest.

EDIT : I'm using WPF

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that... WPF...

Comment: Please also refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551170/combobox-selectedindexchanging) which says that you dont achieve all with dropdown event. Try changing combobox values using updown arrow keys

Comment: @Niraj: Oh, ya. It's not working if I use my keyboard keys! Thanks for pointing that out. So, now how do I go about solving this issue? And looks like I've got to handle a different event. I have tried using Loaded Event but it results in an infinite loop. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be an option to use styles to set the items? e.g.

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeConditionalProperty}"
                             Value="SomeConditionalValue">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{BindingToFindRightItems}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeConditionalProperty}"
                             Value="AnotherValue">
                    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{BindingToFindRightItemsForAnotherValue}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: H.B : Thanks a lot for that. I shall try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: H.B : If you're still there, I got some problem. It seemed to work fine but all of a sudden, it's not working. I am able to debug, the call reaches my property and the required ItemsSource is also assigned. But finally, all my combo boxes have only one value in them, that too the same value. Any idea on why this is happening?

Comment: Sorry, i cannot tell you what is going wrong there without any context, if you need this sorted out please ask another question and provide all the necessary code. Maybe i can help you then. Also try to pin your problem down, see what happens if you change certain things.

Comment: H.B : Sorry, I found the solution (in fact, i had done a terriblemistake). My bad.. I had been using the same field variable (a collection<string>) and used it repeatedly by clearing it in all my collections those are bound to the combo boxes, which apparently was causing problems. Now I'm using different field variables and things are fine! Thanks a lot!